# Using Ghostscript to download protected pdf

Tags: pdf, adobe, ghostscript, drm

I have a PDF that requires the content to be downloaded from a server using a username and password or else it just says "this content is protected" on each page of the pdf.

Can I use ghostscript to be able to get an offline version of this PDF?

Comment: Ghostscript doesn't download files, nor does it remove protection from PDF files. If you know the user name and password you may produce a new PDF file, visually the same as the original, without security applied though. Assuming that the problem is that the file is encrypted.

Comment: Thats exactly what I am trying to do. I want to re-produce the PDF (i know the user/password) without the security. @KenS

Comment: And what's the problem ? I just tried this and it worked well for me. Of course I used a simple file with only password security and simple encryption.

Comment: Is there a reason why you cannot simply ask the creator of the PDF for an unsecured copy ? This does sound awfully like you are trying to circumvent copyright in some way.